# php - LibreOffice stuck generating PDF file from DOCX at the same time

Tags: php, libreoffice

I have a problem where when I convert 2 docx files simultaneously by using LibreOffice (soffice.exe), the LibreOffice hangs. This doesn't happen when converting xslx (Excel) file simultaneously.

My code:

```
exec("C:/LibreOfficePortable/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe -headless -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export -outdir C:\convertTest\ C:\convertTest\l06.docx");
```

and

```
exec("C:/LibreOfficePortable/App/libreoffice/program/soffice.exe -headless -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export -outdir C:\convertTest\ C:\convertTest\l07.docx");
```

I have done some digging, and I think it is probably because the temp file generated by the LibreOffice has the same names when converting 2 docx files simultaneously so it haywires. This is just an assumption though.

I need either a fix or an alternative as good as LibreOffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not convert two files simultaneously.

What I have done in the past is to make the PHP script place files in a polled directory.  Write a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)) (could be a simple shell script or something more complex such as Java) that polls that directory for incoming jobs, and when it sees jobs, it feeds them to LibreOffice one at a time, sending the results to an output directory.

The PHP script, meanwhile, waits for results in the output directory.

Another option is to use a file as a [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)).  The PHP script would create a 0 bytes file before running the job.  If the file already exists, wait for it to go away before converting with LibreOffice, because another job may be running.  After converting, delete the file so that the next job can run.

According to the link:

> PHP provides a file based locking as well as a Mutex class in the pthreads extension.

In my experience, using a lock file is a fragile setup, because if one job goes wrong, everything is stuck.  A Java daemon, however, can be programmed with threads so that if there is a problem, it can still keep going.

LibreOffice is primarily designed for user interaction.  I believe there are command-line based tools for doing such conversions, although I do not have experience with any.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll wait some more for other answers and if there isn't any, yours will have to do.